# write out 12divs using jquery code instead of writing it in the html

Tags: jquery, html

How do i write out 12 divs using jquery such that each one would look similar to this first one:

```
<div class='chart half' >
<h3 id="g1">graph1</h3>
<svg id='chart1'></svg>
</div>
```

and the 12th one would look like this:

```
    <div class='chart half' >
     <h3 id="g12">graph12</h3>
    <svg id='chart12' ></svg>
    </div>
```

I want to write the code that creates the 12 divs as opposed to writing out 12 seperate divs in the html code. The divs would appear as above inside the

I have made a start on this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NVyLb/3/)

Note:I also want to be able to write the graph titles in the jquery code also.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to just have the 12 divs in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NVyLb/4/

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var x = 1; x < 13; x += 1) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="chart half"><h3 id="g' + x + '">Graph' + x + '</h3><svg id="chart' + x + '"></svg></div>');
    }
});
```

You should use a for loop when creating many elements dynamically, and those elements have similar classes/id's/text. On document ready, this for loop runs, creating 12 div's. The `h3` id gets incremented by 1 on each loop, as well as the `svg` id. Also, the `h3` title text gets incremented by 1 each time, so it says Graph1 then Graph2 etc etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/NVyLb/4/

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var x = 1; x < 13; x += 1) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="chart half"><h3 id="g' + x + '">Graph' + x + '</h3><svg id="chart' + x + '"></svg></div>');
    }
});
```

You should use a for loop when creating many elements dynamically, and those elements have similar classes/id's/text. On document ready, this for loop runs, creating 12 div's. The `h3` id gets incremented by 1 on each loop, as well as the `svg` id. Also, the `h3` title text gets incremented by 1 each time, so it says Graph1 then Graph2 etc etc.

On each of the 12 loops it appends the new `div` that includes the `div`, `h3`, `svg`, into the `.container` `div` on the page.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NVyLb/5/) tks, this is what i got is it silly/pointless to declare the $div variabl?